# How to get language name from language code for google translate in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, php, google-apps-script, google-translate

I have a script I'm using with the google translate api. I am translating like this:

```
LanguageApp.translate(content, 'en', 'es')
```

I now need to translate `content` to many more languages, and as languages are added or dropped I don't want to update much, so how can I get the name of a language from its language 'code'?

I'm expecting something like this

```
LanguageApp.getNameFromCode('es')
```

and it would return "spanish" in this case.

How can I achieve this?

If it's not possible, I can use JS to on my frontend, or PHP in my backend, but using GAS is the most preferable way for me.

Comment: I doub't there's too many languages being added to the [ISO-639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) standard these days, I'd suggest keeping a dictionary of them yourself and then matching them with what the [API provides](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages) via [this whatever the SDK provides for this](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/discovering-supported-languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the method you are looking for:

```
List<Language> languages = translate.listSupportedLanguages(target);
```

I shared the Java code, but you can have a look at [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/discovering-supported-languages#listing_supported_languages_in_target_language) and choose the one that fits your application better.